# redirect to page if expiration date = today's date?

Tags: php, sql

I have a site with users on. Each users account has an expiration date in mysql table `subscription_expires`.

Is there a way to redirect a user to another page other than dashboard.php if their profile or the `subscription_expires` is `=` to today's date after an attempt of login in which says their profile has expired.

I've tried to have a go by using `sub_expires` etc., but no luck it still logs the user in if their profile is expired.

Here's my login script:

```
<?php

    if (logged_in()) {
        redirect_to("dashboard.php");
    }

    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");

    // START FORM PROCESSING
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
        $errors = array();

        // perform validations on the form data
        $required_fields = array('email', 'password');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $fields_with_lengths = array('email' => 30, 'password' => 30);
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

        $email = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email']));
        $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
        $hashed_password = md5($password);

        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            // Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
                // email/password authenticated
                // and only 1 match
                $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                $_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];

                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Online' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());


                redirect_to("dashboard.php");
            } else {
                // email/password combo was not found in the database
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox\"><strong>Email/Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                    Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
            }

                } else {
            if (count($errors) == 1) {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">There was 1 error in the form.<div>";


            } else {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.<div>";
            }
        }


    } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">You are now logged out.</div>";
        } 
        $email = "";
        $password = "";
    }
?>
            <?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>
            <?php if (!empty($errors)) { display_errors($errors); } ?>
            <form action="login.php" method="post">

Email<br />
<input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" size="40" maxlength="50" />

  <br />
  <br />
  Password<br />
  <input name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" size="40" maxlength="30" />

  <br />
  <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />


            </form>
```

Comment: Some other general notes: Use exclusive upper-bound with ranges (so, `'<'`), especially when dealing with date/time/timestamp values, and even more so on the web.  You're not using a prepared statement, which, depending on your other functions, could mean you're open to SQL Injection.  You also are using MD5 hashes for passwords, which can be broken trivially, and not using some sort of unique salt.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the "subscription_expires" field in your select query. So you are going to get null for $_SESSION['sub_expires'].  Also, I don't see anywhere in your logic where you try to use the $_SESSION['sub_expires'] value to do anything meaningful, like preventing the user from logging in.  You are just automatically updating your ptb_users table to show them as online before you even do any checking on that value.

Answer (score 0):

You also are using the `'{$hashed_password}'`parameter, without setting it (you set `trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']))` instead. That query almost certainly never returns a value...